# php mailer is not working

Tags: php

Here's my phpmailer code, its not working , dont know where i am getting error.
I have to embed this code in certain script and i think for gmail port no `port no 465` .

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$email=$_POST['email'];
$subject1=$_POST['subject'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
smtpmailer($email,$subject1,$message);

function smtpmailer($to,$subject,$body) { 

    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = "aman****589@gmail.com";  
    $mail->Password = "*****02589";  

    $mail->From     = "aman***589@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Cor****tions";

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
}
}
}
?><html><body>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />
Subject:<br />
<textarea name="subject" id="subject" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea><br />
Message:<br/>
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help ?? where i m getting error?
when i run this script its giving error-

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function smtpmailer() in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpm\index.php on line 8
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare a function with its parameters, before you call it. At the moment, your program is searching for the function `smtpmailer()` - but it is not even defined yet.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$email=$_POST['email'];
$subject1=$_POST['subject'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

function smtpmailer($to,$subject,$body) { 

    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = "aman****589@gmail.com";  
    $mail->Password = "*****02589";  

    $mail->From     = "aman***589@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Cor****tions";

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
}
}
smtpmailer($email,$subject1,$message);
}

?><html><body>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />
Subject:<br />
<textarea name="subject" id="subject" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea><br />
Message:<br/>
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It runs but neither get mail on inbox nor junk.

Comment: If you'r trying local, you might not setup your local Mailer?

Comment: yes i m trying at local , can you tell me how to setup localmailer.?
thanks

Comment: windows | http://inchoo.net/magento/installation-and-configuration-of-local-mail-server-for-windows-hmail-server/ | linux http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/308917-install-and-configure-a-postfix-mail-server

Comment: if i put it online , same things happens, no mail comes.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Declare the function before you call it.